# Cumulative frequency for string occurence

Tags: python, string, pandas, cumulative-frequency

To start off, a little about my problem.

I have a data frame of winners of the champions league cup indexed by years.

Like this, note team names are strings.

```
year    team         need this         year    team      wins to date

1       team1                           1       team1          1
2       team2                           2       team2          1
3       team1                           3       team1          2
4       team3                           4       team3          1
```

I would like to create a new column with cumulative wins, so that i can then plot a line graph of each team and the number of times they have won the cup. ie I need the year on the x axis and the cumulative frequency on the y, with 4 different lines for the top 4 teams.

There is probably an easy way using the count function and a loop but I'm fairly new to python and don't have a very good grasp of these. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: thanks for editing that i was trying to do that myself, dont know how you did it but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at pandas documentation on `groupby`, `transform`, `cumcount`, and `cumsum` (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).
You can groupby team and use transform to do a cumsum on bool result of whether the team is null or not.

```
df
```

Input:

```
   year   team
0     1  team1
1     2  team2
2     3  team1
3     4  team3
```

Do transformation

```
df['wins to date'] = df.groupby('team').transform(lambda x: x.notnull().cumsum())
df
```

or as DSM suggest:

```
df['wins to date'] = df.groupby('team').cumcount()+1
```

output

```
   year   team  wins to date
0     1  team1             1
1     2  team2             1
2     3  team1             2
3     4  team3             1
```

Comment: Maybe just `.cumcount() + 1`?

Comment: @Dsm Yes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to use `groupby` with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html). As in:

```
df.groupby('team').cumsum()
```

Comment: how would i apply this to string values of the team? the cumsum function only appends the strings together (team1team1team1, rather than just digit 3). I'd like to count the number. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: but df['wins to date'] are integers, no? Isn't that the column you want to cumulatively sum?

Comment: oh sorry 'wins to date' is a column id like to create, it hasnt got any digits in it, id like to fill it with the number of times 'team1' won, up to thjat row

Comment: i can't get it to work, the values are NaN. i need to count the recurrences of the string 'team1'

Comment: i tried: groupby and count as well, but the values stay as 1 or NaN, :s